# How to publish an .exe with InstallShield, so that it does not ask for admin rights?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment, installshield

How to publish an .exe with InstallShield, so that it does not ask for admin rights?

Currently I have visual studio 2012 c# project, and I publish a setup.exe
with Limited InstallShield. But then on my own pc, it asks me for admin rights
when I try to run the .exe. How can I escape that? I don't have admin rights on
my pc and I can't test my app like this.

Comment: If you plan to install the app in %PROGRAMFILES%, you're going to need admin rights in order to write in that folder.

Comment: What if I install in other directory? So the admin rights dialog is dependent on the install location? It will show up for some and not for others?

Comment: I haven't used InstallShield before, only regular MSI Installer projects, but you can try change the install path to some directory in the current user folder and see if it still needs admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

A setup.exe file name is going to trigger UAC prompt, this is the effect of the user's security policy "[User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)" by Microsoft and has nothing to do with InstallShield.

You can generate an application manifest to override the requestedExecutionLevel detection with your own requestedExecutionLevel declaration. Put the manifest in the same folder with your setup.exe or embed it into setup.exe as a resource. InstallShield LE supports the latter in the [setup.exe tab of release options.](http://helpnet.installshield.com/isxhelp17/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm)

Comment: I doubt this feature is available in InstallShield **Limited Edition**. The link you provided talks about Express Edition only.